# Binding data to silverlight lineseries chart

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding, linechart

I have a line chart, what I want to do is bind the data from my classList and display it on my line chart. How do i do that? my class contains a string and a double

```
List<myClass> classList = new List<myClass>(); 
classList.Add(class);


<charting:Chart x:Name="MyLineSeriesChart">
    <charting:LineSeries Name="LineChart" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IndependentValuePath="X" DependentValuePath="Y" />
</charting:Chart>
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2imtsv

Comment: i'm able to make it into intervals now. however, there are extra stuff on the top and on the right

Comment: To show x and y axis line draw border or line in edge panel grid(refer first screenshots)

Comment: there is a difference in windows-phone and normal windows form. however, thanks for the code. i could do some reference